# How to diagnose why Query in Microsoft Access is returning wrong results

Tags: microsoft-access, query

I have a database in which I store information about what work our contractor is doing for us.

Basically I store WorkNumber, date when work was done, contract number, subcotnract number (we have separate subcontracts for each of our locations) and then what work was done (this is stored in relation table) form each bill the contractor issues to us.
Common key for relation between bill table and work done table is WorkNumber filed. Here I let Access create its own Index key for each record instead of using actual WoorkNumber from the contractor bill as I suspected that contractor would reset its work number counter to zero at the start of each yer.

Now I have a query to get information about what work the contractor has done in certain time period. So my query checks for all bills that have been issued in such time period and then sums all work that have been done in that period by work type grouping it by subcontract number so I get information what done was done for each location separately.

The problem is that when I try to get information for previous month query also seems to include some information from one of much older bills. You see in the middle of the last year we signed a ne contract with the said contractor which resulted in all subcontractor numbers to be changed. But for some reason the query for previous month also keeps returning information about some work that is based on subcontract that we haven't used since last year.

So I went to manually check every record for the past month to find a possible entry error but there is none.

Then I tried to systematically narrow the query time span to find an exact date which would return such wrong result. And i narrowed it to next:

If I chose date range from 16.06.2021 to 17.06.2021 the query returns wrong results containing no longer used subcontract.

If I chose date range from 17.06.2021 to 18.06.2021 the query also returns wrong results containing no longer used subcontract.

Bit if I chose date range for query as 17.06.2021 to 17.06.2021 (a single day) query correct result not containing no longer used subcontract.

**So how to diagnose** why access query is returning wrong results only where time span spans across 17.06.2021 date but now when the query time span is just 17.06.2021.

Comment: " You see in the middle of the last year we signed a ne contract with the said contractor which resulted in all subcontractor numbers to be changed", are the IDs the same? Run a query to find bills related to a subcontractor but not based on dates. Does it return the correct result?

Comment: The mentioned Query returns correct  results if I chose any time span that does not include date 17.06.2021. Any way I have been successfully using the same query for months even thou the signing of now contract with the mentioned contractor resulted in now subcontract numbers.

Comment: No IDs for new contract and new subcontracts are not the same as the one of old contract and subcontracts. I have designed the database structure so that it assigns its own record IDs instead of using the data in order to avoid problem if multiple contractors might use same numbering system for their bills. So technically I could have multiple bills from multiple contractors with same number but the database will still distinguish them based on contract and subcontract numbers.

Comment: I have even gone and look at raw data in the database to spot an error in data but I can't find one.